# Git uses incorrect user to log into SSH, resulting in Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, key

I'm having an issue with a private git instance, where git is replacing the username in my git operations.

For example, when i run `ssh -T git@privateGithubInstance.com`, ssh can authenticate successfully, but when I run `git ls-remote privateGithubInstance.com:project/repo.git`, git will log in with my local username (as listed from the `whoami` command), and not the git user above. This makes the server throw a publickey error, as git is using the wrong user.

my ssh config is empty, and the only relevant line in my git config is a URL replace which replaces HTTPS with SSH:

```
url.ssh://git@privateGithubInstance.com/project.insteadof=https://privateGithubInstance.com/project
```

note how the replace points to git@ and not myUsername@, meaning there's really no reason that git should try to log in with myUsername.

Why is this happening, and what are the proper steps to fix it?

Comment: `git ls-remote git@privateGithubInstance.com:project/repo.git`

Comment: Use `git@` in your syntax, as phd showed, or configure your ssh (in `~/.ssh/config`) to provide `git@` by default. Your `insteadOf` fires only when you use `https://` syntax, not when you use ssh-like syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insteadOf configuration would only be use for replacing HTTPS URL, which is not the case when you do the `git ls-remote`

Either you use, with `ls-remote`, an SSH URL `git@privateGithubInstance.com:project/repo.git`

Or you use the HTTPS URL (which would then be replaced by the SSH one)

```
git ls-remote https://privateGithubInstance.com/project/repo.git
```